# Как сделать чтобы меню не закрывалось при изменении высоты?

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка, меню

Нашёл адаптивное меню, которое не конфликтует с остальными скриптами. Но возникла проблема. При появлении экранной клавиатуры на смартфоне или просто изменении размера окна меню тут же исчезает. Нужно чтобы оно пропадало только при нажатии. Что там поправить надо? Никак не пойму.
Ссылка на демо скрипта - http://studiosr.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/responsive-multi-menu/index.html

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5264

Answer (score 0):

```
.rmm-dropdown{
  transition:.4s;
  transition-delay:.7s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали сделать так

```
else {
if($('.rmm-menu').is(".rmm-mobile")) return;
            $('.rmm-menu').addClass("rmm-mobile");
            $('.rmm-toggled').show();
            $('.rmm-toggled').addClass("rmm-closed");
```

Мне помогло